# Better way of managing dynamic valuechanges subscriptions on rxjs Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I currently have an use case where I have a form with a formarray inside, in the formarray I can dynamically add formgroups by clicking a button and then each formgroup has 4 formControls. Also each formarray can be deleted at any time.

The thing is, for each form group that's added, I need to subscribe to the valuechanges of each of its 4 fields and then execute a webservice on the subscription.

This is the subscription method, it receives the index of the formgroup im subscribing:

```
  createMultiSubscriber(index: number) {
const getProductsObs$ = merge(
  this.secondaryHolders.controls[index]
    .get('typeDoc')
    .valueChanges.pipe(
      tap((docType) => this.handlerMultiDocType(docType, index))
    ),
  this.secondaryHolders.controls[index].get('document').valueChanges,
  this.secondaryHolders.controls[index].get('email').valueChanges,
  this.secondaryHolders.controls[index].get('expeditionCountry')
    .valueChanges
)
  .pipe(
    debounceTime(500),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap((value) => {
      if (
        this.secondaryHolders.controls[index].get('document').valid &&
        this.secondaryHolders.controls[index].get('typeDoc').valid &&
        this.secondaryHolders.controls[index].get('email').valid &&
        !this.secondaryHolders.controls[index].get('expeditionCountry')
          .invalid
      ) {
        this.isLoadingOtherProducts = true;
        return EMPTY;
      } else {
        this.isLoadingOtherProducts = false;
        return EMPTY;
      }
    })
  )
  .subscribe((response) => {
    this.isLoadingOtherProducts = false;
  });
this.titularSubscribers.push(getProductsObs$);
```

}

At the time where I delete a formarray I delete with it, it's correspondent subscription so it wont stay there. But the problem I'm having is when I'm deleting a formgroup  that's not the last index on the formarray and type something on another existent formgroup on which im getting this error:
[image: Error while deleting]

Here is the delete method:

```
  deleteHolder(index: number): void {
this.secondaryHolders.removeAt(index);
this.titularSubscribers[index].unsubscribe();
```

}

My question is, is there any better way of doing this subscription/desubscription for multiple formgroups method?
Here is a stackblitz example:
[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dr8trd)

Thank you guys in advance!.

Answer (score 0):

For the delete in your html it must be `deleteHolder(i+1)` since you are not deleting your first block. When you have two block you think you are deleting the seconde element but no it is the first.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer! But with that change, it deletes only the last element on the formarray, not the selected index of it